# ClosedXML - Unable to cast IXLRangeRows to IXLRange

Tags: c#, closedxml

I'm using ClosedXML.Excel to read data from excel sheet.
Let's say I have a table similar to this:

[image]

I read this table using `workSheet.RangeUsed()`, which produces type `IXLRange` and I filter the range just to rows containing Division 1, so I do

```
var filteredRows = range.Rows(r => r.Cell(1).GetString().Equals("Division 1"));
```

But then I would like to filter filteredRows based on values in column 2, but I am unable to do it the way above, because filteredRows is of type `IXLRangeRows`.

I tried to cast it to IXLRange, but the casting fails.

How am I able to do the filtration? I'm using it in recursive function, that's why I need the range and filteredRows to be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

If you can start with `IXLRangeRows range = worksheet.RangeUsed().Rows()` and then use

```
IXLRangeRows filteredRows = (IXLRangeRows)range.Where(r => r.Cell(1).GetString().Equals("Division 1"));
IXLRangeRows filteredRows2 = (IXLRangeRows)filteredRows.Where(r => r.Cell(2).GetString().Equals("Subdivision 1.1"));
```

Now you have the same type (`IXLRangeRows`) for every step.

Comment: Well I changed the logic to be able to use IXLRangeRows, but I still get an InvalidCastException (Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[ClosedXML.Excel.IXLRangeRow]' to type 'ClosedXML.Excel.IXLRangeRows')